# Is PC to Digital Radio possible, is there an existing solution?

Tags: ht, audio-interface, digital-voice, computer-control

Is it possible to setup up an interface from a PC to a digital radio that is able to communicate with a Hytera PD702 handheld (450-520MHz) or like type radio?  Or are there off the shelf radios that can manage this out of the box that have a USB connection and a software API?

The research I've done shows this is easily possible with non digital radios.  The information for digital is vague at best.  For example the West Mountain Radio/RIGblaster looked like it could be suitable but they don't support digital.

We are aiming to do 2 things:

1. Send audio from the PC to the handheld
2. Record transmissions from the handhelds

We could hack something together using a USB controlled relay to control the push to talk and route the mic and speaker through an audio card but I really think this has been done before and a lot more professionally.

Comment: Not completely sure what you are asking, but the pinout for the audio interface for that radio is here:  https://www.hamdigitaal.nl/download/algemene-informatie/_Hytera_Steckerbelegungen.pdf It would be easy enough to build your own interface and connect it to a computer sound card or RigBlaster-like thing.

Comment: Maybe not so much.  It may be the wrong pinout.  But the correct one does exist somewhere.  What you are describing is fairly easy to do however a computer-controlled transmitter could have legal issues.  What are you planning to do with this?

Comment: If you want to record transmissions, maybe a cheap rtl-sdr and receiver software instead of using a Hytera handset is easier and more versatile and also capable of monitoring a whole band instead of just a single channel?